Return 0 values when using count + group by from a CTE
I have a table like this:



customer_id
churn_label
churn_score




2988-QRAJY
Yes
10


2919-HBCJO
No
40



churn_label = 'Yes' means the customer churned.
churn_label = 'No' means the customer didn't churn.
I'm trying to make groups of churn_score into columns like 1-30, 31-50, etc. I am using a case statement for that. After I create the groups and make them into a column I want to put that into a CTE and query from it while grouping the churn count of the customers by the groups so it will look something like this:



churn_score_group
churn_count




10-30
950


31-50
1450



However, some groups would not have any customers who churned, in other words, the count column would be NULL so the count function wouldn't return those rows.
I want to return the rows with the groups that don't have any customers who churned and for it to return a 0 value. I read that you can use a LEFT JOIN to do that but I am not sure this is possible with a self JOIN. I am using the WHERE condition to filter for customers with churn_label = 'Yes'.
WITH churn_score_groups AS
(
SELECT 
Customer_id,
Churn_value,
CASE
        WHEN churn_score BETWEEN 1 AND 30 THEN '1-30'
        WHEN churn_score BETWEEN 31 AND 50 THEN '31-60'
        WHEN churn_score BETWEEN 51 AND 80 THEN '51-80'
        WHEN churn_score BETWEEN 81 AND 100 THEN '81-100'
        END AS churn_score_group
FROM churn_status
)
SELECT 
churn_score_group,
COUNT(*) as count
FROM churn_score_groups
WHERE churn_label = 'Yes'
GROUP BY churn_score_group;

So far I understand that count cannot return null values. I can't figure out how to return them as 0's.
Thanks.

Where do those groups come from, what's the logic behind them? If they are always the same and are not based on the real ranges in your table, I like this answer and think it's sufficient. If you need a more dynamic solution, meaning the groups should automatically be created based on the values in your table, please explain how.

@Jonas Metzler
The values on the new column 'churn_score_group' are taken from a column that contains values from 1-100 and they are integer type.
there's no real logic behind them or something; I decided to group them like that.

This means you don't need a dynamic query, but will always use the same groups? Then I think T N ' answer is the best way.

You can define the churn group names and ranges in a VALUES source and then LEFT JOIN them to your data. This way, each group will always be present in the result.
SELECT CG.churn_score_group, COUNT(CS.churn_score) as count
FROM  (
    VALUES
        ('1-30', 1, 30),
        ('31-60', 31, 60),
        ('51-80', 51, 80),
        ('81-100', 81, 100)
) CG(churn_score_group, Low, High)
LEFT JOIN churn_status CS
    ON CS.churn_score BETWEEN CG.Low AND CG.High
    AND CS.churn_label = 'Yes'
GROUP BY CG.churn_score_group;

Note that the COUNT() function references a column in the left-joined table so as to only count matching rows.
If you want a specific order in your result, you can add ORDER BY CG.Low to the query, but you would then need to also add that column to the GROUP BY.
...
GROUP BY CG.churn_score_group, CG.Low
ORDER BY CG.Low;

Sample results (for values 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, and 100):



churn_score_group
count




1-30
3


31-60
2


51-80
0


81-100
1



See this db<>fiddle for a demo.
ADDENDUM
One drawback of the above approach is that the join may cause four separate table scans of the source data - one for each group.
An alternative that eliminates the multiple table scans is to:

Calculate all of the sums across multiple columns using conditional aggregation, and then
Unpivoting the data into its final row-oriented form.

SELECT V.churn_score_group, V.count
FROM (
    SELECT
        COUNT(CASE WHEN churn_score BETWEEN  1 AND  30 THEN 1 END) AS [1-30],
        COUNT(CASE WHEN churn_score BETWEEN 31 AND  60 THEN 1 END) AS [31-60],
        COUNT(CASE WHEN churn_score BETWEEN 61 AND  80 THEN 1 END) AS [61-80],
        COUNT(CASE WHEN churn_score BETWEEN 81 AND 100 THEN 1 END) AS [81-100]
    FROM churn_status
    WHERE churn_label = 'Yes'
) S
CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES
        (1, '1-30',   [1-30]),
        (2, '31-60',  [31-60]),
        (3, '61-80',  [61-80]),
        (4, '81-100', [81-100])
) V(ordinal, churn_score_group, count)
ORDER BY V.ordinal

Although SQL Server supports an UNPIVOT operation, the above uses a CROSS APPLY (VALUES ...) technique that allows insertion of an ordinal that is later used to control the result order.
See this db<>fiddle for a demo that compares execution plans.

I'm a little confused with how you're defining the score groups: are they delimited 30 by 30, or maybe it's a sequence 30,20,30... It's not clear to me, so any clarifications are welcome on this matter.
Also in your query you introduce a field churn_value that isn't present in the model definition described above, so I'll assume it's a cast from the not so type-safe field churn_label (I recommend replacing this field with an integer or boolean one, anyways).
So, assuming a sequence skipping thirty by thirty, and using a field churn_value with values 0 (No) and 1 (Yes), you can do something like:
SELECT
  DIV(churn_score, 30)::varchar || '-' || DIV(churn_score, 30) + 1 as churn_score_group, -- integer division
  SUM(churn_value) -- since 0 doesn't weigh on the SUM, you can avoid filtering it
FROM churn_status GROUP BY DIV(churn_score, 30);

If, otherwise, your score groups are not equal in size, you can define a CTE (or a real table, if performance is a relevant issue for your case) with the groups. For this, I would highly recommend treating the higher and lower bounds for each group as separate fields. This would make determining which row corresponds to each group trivial, avoiding type-casting and transformations. Anyway, after that you can present the group as you like. Something like this:
WITH score_groups(min, max) AS (VALUES (1, 30), (31, 60), (61, 80), (81, 100))
SELECT
  sg.min::varchar || '-' || sg.max::varchar AS churn_score_group,
  COALESCE(SUM(ch.churn_value), 0) as churn_count
FROM churn_status
RIGHT JOIN score_groups sg ON ch.churn_score BETWEEN sg.min AND sg.max
GROUP BY ch.customer_id;

Please note that this approach would return (<id>, NULL, N) for any records that don't fall between the score groups YOU defined literally (in my case, any score higher than 100 or lower than 1. If this is a problem, I would consider a dedicate function for generating the groups. If not and the groups are pre-defined and limited, this approach can help your case in retrieving ALL groups even when they don't have any matching churns.

Note that the original question is tagged as sql-server..

I might have used some non-standard syntax, as I'm used to working with postgres. Would you favor us with the insights about which syntax I'm mis-using in order to run this query in sql-server? Or are you only allowed to point out mistakes?

@AgusNeira Please avoid such unkind language as in the last question of your comment. Did you note they provided a fiddle in their answer? You can check your query there and see if/which mistakes it contains.

@AgusNeira it's your responsibility to ensure your answer is in the technology the question is requesting - not anyone else's.

Here is a fiddle that I believe is a fair translation of your Postgres query. SQL server CTEs do not support direct VALUES references (don't know why), but they do support a subquery that references VALUES. Type cast syntax is different and string concatenation syntax is different. However, for this use case, both can be accomplished using the SQL Server CONCAT() function, which implicitly converts types to strings. I also added the missing ch table alias.

@TN You need to use COUNT rather than SUM in this fiddle to produce the expected result.

@JonasMetzler - I was trying to remain true to the Agus Neira's original Postgres code. Assuming that churn_value is an integer (not a bit) with only values 0 or 1, a SUM() may work. But I agree that a COUNT(ch.any_column) togerher with a ch.churn_value = 1 (or ch.churn_label = 'Yes') in the join condition would be better.

I did change the GROUP BY, which was a significant logic change that I didn't enumerate in my earlier comment.

@AgusNeira sorry, I edited the post. The' churn_value' in the WHERE clause was meant to be 'churn_label' = 'Yes' for people who churned.

@TN the fiddle you mentioned which is a fair translation of the postgres is not working for me, btw. I tried using COUNT instead of SUM as Jonas suggested but that returns the wrong values for the count.

@Lana - Does the other answer give you the desired results? I'll leave it to Agus Neira to fix any remaining issues with this answer.
